# Identify lines in text containing whole 'names' with Regex (updated question)

Tags: python, regex, parsing

NOTE: This is a repost of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66666802/regex-to-identify-lines-containing-string-as-whole-chunk-of-text) with substantial attempt at clarification. I hope it's clearer!

I have a file with a bunch of lines most of which contain what I'll call a 'name' (a string of alphanumeric characters and possibly underscores/spaces, but no other characters), along with in most cases an `=` and some numbers and special characters. Most lines contain some of each. Sometimes the 'names' are preceded by other characters e.g. `:` or `!` or others.

More tricky - sometimes the 'names' are subsets of other 'names'. For example:

```
# ignore the line numbers 00| etc.
01| 1 <= foo bar baz = 2 <= 3
02| :NI=5
03| :PENG = 7
04| 42 <= foo = 50 <= 90
05| bar = 27
06| NI PENG NEEWOM = 1000
07| 2 <= PENG2 = 3 <= 4
08| PENG PENG PENG
09| PENG=5
10| NI = 3
11| foo3 bar = 7
12| :fo4o=2
```

Here for example `foo` is the entire 'name' in line 4, but not in line 1 where the 'name' is `foo bar baz`. Likewise `PENG` is the entire 'name' in line 3 and line 9, but not in line 6 (`NI PENG NEEWOM`), line 7 (`PENG2`), or line 8 (`PENG PENG PENG`). `bar` is the entire 'name' in line 5, but not line 1 (`foo bar baz`) or line 11 (`foo3 bar`).

I would like to be able to identify lines in which a given search key is an *entire* 'name' but not part of a name. Again, rules for a 'name' are that it is a continuous string of alphanumeric/underscore/space characters but no others e.g. `=`, `:`, `!` etc.

If it helps, in all relevant lines the entire name will be followed by a `=`.

Doesn't need to be done in a single line of code - if it takes two steps to identify the line and then pull it out, that's fine.

Another way I can think of the problem is parsing each line into chunks, splitting such that each 'name' ends up being a whole chunk, and then matching the search key to whole chunks:

```
for line in text:
    chunks = line.split(<any non-alphanumeric/underscore/space character>)
    if key in chunks:
        return True
```

But that seems like it would be quite inefficient, to split every single line in the text (and I'm not sure how to do the split). But it gets at the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex with flag `re.I` to find a "name" within a line:

```
[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*(?: +[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)*
```

1. `[a-z_]` - matches an alpha or underscore character
2. `[a-z0-9_]*` - matches 0 or more alphanumeric or underscore characters
3. `(?: +[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)*` - **matches 0 or more groups of:** one or more spaces followed by an alpha or underscore followed by 0 or more alphanumeric or underscore characters

In effect, each part of a "name" must begin with an alpha or underscore character (but not a numeric).

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/L896GO/1/)

```py
import re

text = """1 <= foo bar baz = 2 <= 3
 :NI=5
| :PENG = 7
 42 <= foo = 50 <= 90
 bar = 27
 NI PENG NEEWOM = 1000
 2 <= PENG2 = 3 <= 4
 PENG PENG PENG
 PENG=5
 NI = 3
 foo3 bar = 7
 :fo4o=2"""

lines = text.strip().split('\n')

def find(key):
    for line in lines:
        m = re.search(r'[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*(?: +[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)*', line, re.I)
        if m:
            name = m[0]
            if key == name:
                print(line)
                return True

print(find('NI PENG NEEWOM'))
```

Prints:

```
 NI PENG NEEWOM = 1000
True
```

Comment: In giving this a try, `print(find('foo bar baz')) ` returned `None`.  Is that the expected result?

Comment: Oops, no. I apologize. When I copied `[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*` from the beginning of the regex to the latter part of the regex, I had left off the final `*` character. It is now present and it should work now.